# How to subscribe only to the questions of a specific user's feed?

Tags: support, users, feed, subscription

Is there a way to subscribe only to a feed of only the questions of a certain user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaict, you cannot subscribe to just the questions; the following feed will give you a user's questions and answers.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/USER-ID
```

Your meta feed is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/147923