# Get my questions feed to my private webpage?

Tags: feature-request, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to subscribe only to the questions of a specific user's feed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56861/how-to-subscribe-only-to-the-questions-of-a-specific-users-feed)

Is there a way I can get a rss feed for only my asked questions? I would like to link this in to my private page like a twitter feed.

Comment: @YOU: Exactly what i need thanks!